# ActiveModel::UnknownAttributeError: unknown attribute 'logo' for Gym when uploading a logo to Cloudinary

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postman, cloudinary, rails-api

I am a RoR beginner and I'm getting this error in the rails console when I make a POST request to upload a logo in the gyms_controller create action.
[image]

[image]
Here is my code:

db/migrate/20210802173948_add_logo_to_gyms.rb

```
class AddLogoToGyms < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    add_column :gyms, :logo_url, :string
  end
end
```

app/controllers/api/v1/admin/gyms_controller.rb

```
  def create

    amenities = Amenity.find(amenity_ids)

    gym = Gym.new(gym_params)

    gym.amenities << amenities

    gym.save!

    logo = gym_params.extract!(:logo)[:logo]

    gym.upload_logo(logo)

    render json: GymBlueprint.render(gym, root: :data)
  end


  PERMITTED =
    %i[name tier address1 address2 state_code zip_code website_url latitude
      longitude main_photo_url photo_urls schedule_photo_url logo]

  def gym_params
    params
      .require(:gym)
      .permit(PERMITTED)
  end
```

app/models/gym.rb

```
  def upload_logo(logo)
    res = Cloudinary::Uploader.upload(logo, public_id: "users/images/#{id}")

    self.logo_url= res['secure_url']

    save!
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

You should extract the `logo` from the permitted params first before attempting to do the record save.

```
logo = gym_params.extract!(:logo)

gym = Gym.new(gym_params)
gym.amenities << amenities
gym.save!
```

This is because `logo` does not exist in your `gyms` table. The cause of the error is right there in the error message.